# SSL issues connecting to Redshift using python

Tags: python, database, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-redshift

I am facing an issue connecting to the redshift database in one of the aws regions. So, I have a redshift cluster in the us-east-2 region and the ap-southeast-1 region each. I used the below python code snippet to connect to redshift in both the regions.

```
import redshift_connector
import logging
 
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
 
connection = redshift_connector.connect(
        database='my_db',
        host='redshift_host',
        port=5439,
        user='username',
        password='password'
)
 
cur = connection.cursor()
```

The above code snippet successfully connects to Redshift in us-east-2 region. But for the database in ap-southeast-1, I am seeing the error: `redshift_connector.error.InterfaceError: Server refuses SSL`.

The debug logs for the connection error to the ap-southeast-1 redshift cluster looks like:

```
DEBUG:redshift_connector.core:Sending SSLRequestMessage to BE
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/logging/_init_.py", line 1110, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redshift_connector/core.py", line 666, in _init_
    raise InterfaceError("Server refuses SSL")
redshift_connector.error.InterfaceError: Server refuses SSL
```

I'm confused as to why there is an SSL issue with one region's redshift cluster but not the other. Does Redshift use different certificates for different regions' clusters?

For additional context: I used awscli to connect to redshift cluster in ap-southeast-1 region and that worked. So this confirms that all the Security groups and NACL settings are working correctly, except that I am seeing SSL issue for this region connection when using Python libraries. Any guidance on this is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-ssl-support.html#connect-using-ssl

Comment: @MitchWheat Thank you for pointing to this documentation. I already added this cert bundle to the keychain store, but that didn't help with the issue.

Comment: Is your Python instance using the https://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-downloads/amazon-trust-ca-bundle.crt SSL connection? Not sure how your Redshift clusters are configured but try downloading the above file and run `export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=xxx.crt` (pointing to the downloaded CRT file) before running your Python script.